# Wix: (Javascript) Carry information from a page to another

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, global-variables

Issue: Unable to jump and filter information on webpage based off the information from another webpage

Background/Intended behavior:
I have 3 web pages: 1. Home Page 2. Law Page  3. Medical Page.
Pages 2: Law & 3: Medical, have checkboxes that can filter a repeater of linked images on that page.

From the Home Page the user selects from two dropdown lists: Task and Location. Both task and location are required prior to clicking on a search button.  When button is clicked, if the task == a Law task, then user will jump to the law page and the repeater will filter by the task selected and location.  (Example: Task = fire fighter / Location = Dallas)
Expected Result:

1. User jumps to Law page
2. Repeater is filtered by fire fighters in Dallas

The same behavior would apply if a Medial task was selected instead of a Law task. (Example: Task = dentist / Location = Dallas)
Expected Result:

1. User jumps to Medical page
2. Repeater is filtered by dentist in Dallas

Problem 1: I have searched a lot on Wix.com on how to code for a page to jump to another page based off the information entered.  I desire to do an if statement checking the value of the task dropdown list, but I cannot find out how to jump to another page using javascript code in wix.

Problem 2: I also desire to carryover values from one page to be applied in another.  Should I just have a global variables that by default is blank but can be altered between all three pages?  Then upon load of pages 2 & 3 use that values for the variables to display the filters?

Comment: "jumping" from one paging to another is a matter of utilizing the ```location.href``` method unless you have other restrictions. And to carry information from one page to another you need to first save those information into something like web storage then access them once the other page has loaded. Feel free to comment if you have further questions.

Comment: *Local web storage to not confuse what I meant by web storage.

Comment: Look into [location.search](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/search). You probably can use that to retreive the variables you need from the `href`. Something like `domain.com/law.html?task=dentist&location=Dallas`

Comment: If you do not want to reveal the variables in the address bar, then look into [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), which may look a bit more complicated at first, but more powerful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your assistance with finding a solution.  It is a simple question, but becomes very complicated as it pertains to the Wix platform and using their API.

Solution 1: I used wix-location module to redirect user to another page.  Relocation worked as desired.
Solution 2: I used wix-storage to store value across pages.  Information was stored as desired, and recalled using the session.getItem().

[HOME PAGE]

import wixLocation from 'wix-location';
import {session} from 'wix-storage';

export function exploreSearchButton_click(event) {

```
if(($w('#categoryDropdown').value.length>0)&&($w('#stateLocationDropdown').value.length>0))
{
    session.setItem("location",$w('#stateLocationDropdown').value);

    switch($w('#categoryDropdown').value)
    {
        case "Doctor" :
            session.setItem("category",0);
            wixLocation.to("/medical-field");
            break;
        case "Dentist" :
            session.setItem("category",1);
            wixLocation.to("/medical-field");
            break;
            ...
        case "Police Officer": 
             session.setItem("category",0);
            wixLocation.to("/civil-service-law");
            break;
        case "Fire Fighter": 
             session.setItem("category",1);
            wixLocation.to("/civil-service-law");
            break;
      ...
        default: 
            console.log("Did not jump to another page.");
    }
}
```

}

[MEDICAL PAGE]

import {session} from 'wix-storage';

$w.onReady(function () {

```
let newCategory = parseInt(session.getItem("category"));

if(newCategory>=0)
{
    $w('#categoriesCheckboxGroup').selectedIndices = [newCategory];
    $w('#stateLocationDropdown').value = session.getItem("location");
}
        displayServicesInRepeater("medical-field");
```

Thank you all for your assistance.

Answer (score -2):

With php you can use the if and else attributes with the html form attribute you can use checkboxes and with if you can redirect the user to the desired page with an echo ‘window.location’.

Comment: first OP never asked anything about PHP. Second your answer only refers to a small portion of what OP asked. Please aim for helping when answering a question not just to get points.

Comment: [Wix](https://www.wix.com/) does give any PHP support.